# Update VirtualBox differencing image parent

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, disk-image

I have created several VirtualBox VMs, each one writing to a differencing image on top of a shared "base" image, containing a clean Ubuntu install.

The disk images look like this:

```
Base Image
|-VM 1
| |-VM 3
|-VM 2
```

Each VM image is a differencing image.

Now, I want to add a program to the base image.

Is it possible to make a change to the base image that will propagate to all 3 VMs?

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: That's not possible, a new Image will always create a new branch in the _snapshot-tree_. What I do, when i want to have an _add-on_ for all the branches of the snapshot-tree or for new VMs, is to create a new .vdi, I can make changes in it and it has effect for every snapshot/VM, when i reattach it.

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 I'm not sure what you mean by creating a new vdi and reattaching it. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: You create in the `Virtual Media Manager`of VBox a new Hard Disc (=_.vdi_). You add the program onto this disc and you can attach this virtual hard drive to any VM you like. If this workaround is a compromiss for you, i can explain it more exactly